# Abbreviation for "ETA" in Spanish?

Tags: coloquialismos, abreviaturas

Is there an equivalent in spanish for ETA (Estimated Time of Arrival)?

In English, if I want to ask someone when something will be finished, I can briefly ask:

```
ETA?
```

Is there an equivalent abbreviation or shorthand way to ask someone when they will arrive or when they expect a task will be finished?

Comment: It's generally for when someone will arrive somewhere and not when something will be finished...

Comment: I don't know about Spanish, but in English it's very common for a colleague to ask another colleague `ETA?` to inquire when the given task will be completed.

Comment: Yeah, well, I don't work in a company but I hear it all the time re time of arrival for car trips and suchlike.

Answer (score 3):

En español no se utilizan siglas para frases, excepto:

- Siglas provenientes de otros idiomas (CIA, FBI)
- Elementos de otros idiomas, principalmente inglés, que ya vienen con
  nombre según su sigla (CD, DVD, USB)
- Vocabulario técnico específico (UCI, FTP)
- Marcas comerciales (BNP, STP)

Pero nunca frases hechas en español se transforman en siglas para uso cotidiano. En casos extremos, se puede obviar una palabra de una frase, pero jamás convertirla en sigla.

---

In Spanish, acronyms are not used for phrases, except:

- Acronyms from other languages (CIA, FBI)
- Elements from other languages, mainly English, that already come with names according to its acronym (CD, DVD, USB)
- Specific technical vocabulary (UCI, FTP)
- Trademarks (BNP, STP)

But phrases made in Spanish are never transformed into acronyms for everyday use. In extreme cases, a word can be omitted from a phrase, but never converted into an acronym.

Comment: you mean kids don't say `bd` for `buenos días` or "qt?" for `¿Qué tal?` My English-speaking brain finds that impossible to fathom. I think disgust for using a software keyboard (and language hacks to optimize its use) on a mobile device is universal in all languages.

Comment: En  inglés tampoco. Estimated time of arrival (ETA) no es una frase.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield Acronyms are not shortened SMS message uses.

Comment: My question is about colloquial abbreviations used by Spanish-speakers, not formal acronyms

Comment: No, It doesn't exist, we don't say qt or bd, or any similar thing

Comment: Bueno se dice, por ejemplo, la ONU. Hay otros pero no me vienen ahora a la cabeza.

Comment: SI, es más o menos lo descrito en la respuesta UN = ONU, está explicado [aquí](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/siglas-y-acronimos-claves-de-redaccion/)

Comment: @MichaelAltfield *–My English-speaking brain finds that impossible to fathom–* Well, the first thing you should do to learn a foreign language is to get rid of this way of thinking 

Comment: SI se usan abreviaturas, sobre todo de nombres propios de empresas, entidades del gobierno o instituciones del gobierno, a tal punto que las personas olvidan o no saben de donde salieron esas abreviaturas.
En Colombia: DANE, Departamento Nacional de Estadística; DIAN, Departamento de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales; MINTIC, Ministerio de Tecnologiías de la Información y Comunicaciones. Y otras tantas así hay en cada país

Comment: @MichaelAltfield, en el español coloquial, hablado y escrito se habla y se escribe completo, nada de abreviaturas para frases como se acostumbra en inglés (que hace tan oscuro la comunicación para los no nativos). Las abreviaturas que se usan son principalmente para nombre propios de empresas, como Avianca, o para ciertos países como EE.UU (para Estados Unidos). o para entidades del gobierno.

Answer (score 2):

Qué es el certificado de retraso de vuelo?
Un certificado de retraso es un documento que acredita que un vuelo ha experimentado una incidencia y especifica la **hora estimada de llegada** al destino final. Este certificado puede ser emitido por la compañía aérea o por AENA, la entidad responsable de la gestión de aeropuertos en España.

[ayuda aerolineas](https://www.reclamador.es/ayuda/aerolineas/que-es-el-certificado-de-retraso-de-vuelo/)

In the Boletín Oficial del estado:

**Hora estimada de llegada** (HEL) de un envío
[BOE+Spanish+ published laws](https://www.boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=DOUE-L-2004-81062)

Comment: `ETA?` is 4 characters. `hora estimada de llegada?` is 25 characters. Are you saying I can use `HEDL?`? Or are you saying that no alternative exists in Spanish? Also `ETA` isn't asking for hours and sometimes the answer is months or years in the future. It doesn't seem like asking for `hora..` is appropriate. Or is `FEDL?` used in the Spanish-speaking world?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield ETA is three characters, not four.

Comment: The question mark is the fourth character.

Comment: You can use HEL but we forewarned they don't use it out of its original context like we do in English. We use it in everyday speech all the time.

Comment: FYI, *hora* means *time* in Spanish. ¿ Qué hora es? What time is it?

Answer (score 1):

Como ya dijeron antes, en el español no solemos utilizar abreviaturas para comunicarnos a no ser que provengan de fuera, como FBI, CIA etc...

En mi caso particular (que soy Cabin Crew) solo he usado ETA (Estimated Time Arrival / hora estimada de llegada) en aviación, y tiene su significado y protocolo. Un ETA no es para decir a que hora llegamos a tal ciudad, un ETA es parte de la respuesta a un procedimiento de emergencia en un vuelo.

Viene de lo que es un TELSI, que es un proceso a seguir en una emergencia.

- Tipo de emergencia
- Estimated Time Arrival
- Lugar de aterrizaje
- Señal de protección para tripulación y para pasajeros
- Instrucciones especiales si fuese necesario

Pero jamás he usado o escuchado eso en una conversación ni en España ni en LATAM. Es más, si en España preguntas a cualquiera [que es ETA](https://www.elmundo.es/eta/historia/) te dirán que hace referencia a un [grupo terrorista](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euskadi_Ta_Askatasuna)